# How to make the Path Class of pathlib module work in case sensitive mode ?

Tags: python, directory

I am using `pathlib` module to check whether an specific directory exists or not. If not, then the directory has been created.

```
    file_or_directory=Path(path+"/"+mobile_no+"/"+ "CV")

    if file_or_directory.exists():
        print(mobile_no+"/"+"CV" + "  directory  exits---")
    else:
        print(mobile_no+"/"CV"  --directory does not exit. --So Create it")
        file_or_directory.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

But, the problem is that normally in windows file system (Both `NTFS` and `FAT`) directory works in case insensitive mode.

According the the example, if a directory called "CV"  has been created but I might want to create another directory named "cv" uniquely  to be treated completely different from "CV" in terms of sub-directories.

Is there any way to create directories in case sensitive ? I am using windows 10 and  x64 machine.

Comment: windows file systems are case insensitive! UNIX systems are case sensitive. you can set specific folders in windows to be case sensitive. to do so follow [this](https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/enable-case-sensitive-file-and-folder-names/)
So pathlib follows whatever OS/filesystem you are using on. Personally, I prefer case insensitive file system as it makes things easier and I dont really see a benefit in filesystems being case sensitive. but this is just my personal preference nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this existed back when this question was asked, but it's possible today:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/case-sensitivity

Python doesn't support it properly, though, since pathlib assumes (now incorrectly) that all Windows paths are case-insensitive.